# How do I edit .bash_profile with Visual Studio Code? It gives me a permission error

Tags: visual-studio-code, bash

I want to edit .bash_profile with VS Code, but it presents a permission error when I try to save. Sublime typically prompts me with a Administrator login prompt.

Here's my current workflow...

1. From the Terminal, code ~/.bash_profile
2. Edit file in VS Code
3. Command+S
4. Permission Error: denied

Comment: Does .bash_profile already exist? If so you may not own the file. Is this OS X? What does `ls -al .bash_profile` say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running vscode under `sudo` permissions is coming in the April release. Initially you will need to launch a new instance of VSCode and it will *only* be able to edit root-owned files, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3068 for more details on the feature.

However, I recommend you change the ownership of `~/.bash_profile` though as there's not reason you shouldn't be owning that file:

```
sudo chown YOUR_USER_NAME ~/.bash_profile
```